# my gridview is hiding the data in column

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a GridView named `gridview1` and I am assigning it the data through a datatable as below.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cls_Connection.connection);
con.Open();

SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter();
sd.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select d.id,e.Name,d.type from Employee_Details e join designation d on e.id=d.id and d.type='"+atten_cmb_type.Text+"'",con);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sd.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

con.Close();
```

The gridview contains the data and only shows it in the column when the column is clicked and hides it again. Note:I am doing all this in the ComboBox `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

And I had a ListView before which I deleted and used a GridView instead. All other gridviews in my application work fine.

this is my designer code

```
    this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(456, 111);
        this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
        this.dataGridView1.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(768, 315);
        this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 20;
```

Comment: post your designer code also, which will help to identify the problem quickly

Comment: Perhaps you can find a difference in the properties with the other gridviews?

Comment: there wasn't any difference. i checked it.let me post my designer code.

Comment: You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: the same query and procedure works fine in another project

Comment: @KiranHegde i've added my designer code.please take a look

Comment: it only shows the data of the selected row